# No core dumps when linking to libkcapi

Tags: c++, linux

I have a Linux C++ application which links to libkcapi (Linux Kernel Crypto API User Space Interface Library).

The application fails to produce a core dump when I test with the following method:

- ulimit -c unlimited
- run application
- kill -6 pid_of_application

But if the dependency on libkcapi is removed then core dumps are created as expected.

Why would libkcapi prevent core dump creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source, libkcapi intentionally disables core dumps.

From kcapi-kernel-if.c:

```
/* Disable the dumping of this process as we handle with keys */
if (prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE, 0) < 0)
    kcapi_dolog(KCAPI_LOG_ERR,
            "Cannot set prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE)");
```